# How to access ModelState in UseExceptionHandler

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have domain service that throws a custom `DomainServiceValidationException` for a business validation. I want to globally capture the exception and return in ModelState. My current working solution is using `ExceptionFilterAttribute`

```
public class ExceptionHandlerAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILogger<ExceptionHandlerAttribute> _logger;

    public ExceptionHandlerAttribute(ILogger<ExceptionHandlerAttribute> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        
        if (context == null || context.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            return;
        }

       if(context.Exception is DomainServiceValidationException)  
       {
          context.ModelState.AddModelError("Errors", context.Exception.Message);
          context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
          context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
       }
       else
       {
            handle exception
       }
    }
```

}

I want to know if there is any way to access ModelState in UseExceptionHandler middleware

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
{            
        app.UseExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlerOptions()
        {
            ExceptionHandler = async (context) =>
            {
                var ex = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>().Error;

               // how to access to ModelState here                        
                
            }
        });                
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Shorten answer:

No, you cannot access ModelState in UseExceptionHandler middleware.

### Explanation:

Firstly you need to know **ModelState is only available after Model Binding**.

Then Model Binding invokes before `Action Filters` and after `Resource Filters`(See Figure 1). But `Middleware` invokes before Filters(See Figure 2).

Figure 1:

[image]

Figure 2:

[image]

Reference:

[How Filters work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#how-filters-work)

### Conclusion:

That is to say, you can not get the `ModelState` in `UseExceptionHandler` middleware.

### Workaround:

You can only store the `ModelState` automatically in Filters(Action Filters or Exception Filters or Result Filters), then you can use it within middleware.

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlerOptions()
{
    ExceptionHandler = async (context) =>
    {
        var ex = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>().Error;
        // how to access to ModelState here                        
        var data = context.Features.Get<ModelStateFeature>()?.ModelState;
    }
});
```

Reference:

[How to store ModelState automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52379243/11398810)