# Response wrapper in Asp.net Core Web Api

Tags: asp.net-core

I have built a response wrapper as per alltej's answer shown in the below link:

[How can I wrap Web API responses(in .net core) for consistency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748900/how-can-i-wrap-web-api-responsesin-net-core-for-consistency)

When a try to read the content of the response after the api call I get the following. The sample json is value in parameters.

```
response = await _apiClient.GetAsync("search/getParameter");
parameters = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

{"Version":"1.0","StatusCode":404,"ErrorMessage":"Request not found. The specified uri does not exist","Result":null}
```

How can I make response.Content point to the "Result" in the JSON.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [AutoWrapper](https://github.com/proudmonkey/AutoWrapper) for Http response consistency, and use [AutoWrapper.Server](https://github.com/proudmonkey/AutoWrapper.Server) to unwrap the `Result` property at the server.

Comment: is autowrapper compitable with xml output? I cant make it work if I want xml output

Comment: No. AutoWrapper does not support XML at the moment. Please submit a feature request so we can add support for it in the future versions.

Answer (score 0):

By default, an ASP.NET Core app doesn't provide a status code page for HTTP status codes, such as 404 - Not Found. The app returns a status code and an empty response body.

You can customize that in your middleware like :

```
var readToEnd = new StreamReader(memoryStream).ReadToEnd();

if (context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)
{
    readToEnd += "{ \"result\":\"Not Found\" }";
}
```